# Why do I get this TypeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I believe this error means I can't include a variable in a loop however I am struggling to see a way around....

the error is

```
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got unicode.
```

The problem the book tried to ask me is:

> Try wring a program the will prompt for an number and print the correct times table (up to 12).

This is my code:

```
def main():
    pass    
choice = raw_input("Which times table would you like")    
print ("This is the", choice , "'s times table to 12")    

var1 = choice*12 + 1

for loopCounter in range (0,var1,choice):
    print(loopCounter)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change `raw_input()` to `int(raw_input())` it might work. Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're learning Python 2 instead of Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `raw_input` function gives you a *string,* not an integer. If you want it as an integer (such as if you want to multiply it by twelve or use it in that `range` call), you need something such as:

```
choice = int(raw_input("Which times table would you like"))
```

There are potential issues with this simplistic solution (e.g., what happens when what you enter is *not* a number), but this should be enough to get past your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error just means that it got a unicode value when an integer was assumed. 
That happens because you use `raw_input` for `choice`.

Edit: `raw_input` does not interpret your input. `input` does.

Answer (score -1):

Your program will run with a few changes.

```
def main():
    pass    
choice = input("Which times table would you like")    
print ("This is the " + choice + "'s times table to 12")    

var1 = int(choice)*12 + 1

for loopCounter in range (0,var1,int(choice)):
    print(loopCounter)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now you may want to adjust it more so that you get the correct output, the above will compile and run.